# Efficiently get the size of a parameter pack up to a certain index

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-meta-programming

I want to be able to determine the number of bytes that are in a subset of a parameter pack from 0 to a given index.

Right now I'm using a non-constexpr way of doing this.  Below is my code:

```
template <size_t index, typename... args> struct pack_size_index;

template <size_t index, typename type_t, typename... args>
struct pack_size_index <index, type_t, args...> {
    static const size_t index_v = index;

    static const size_t value(void) {
        if (index_v > 0) {
            return sizeof(type_t) + pack_size_index<index - 1, args...>::value();
        }

        return 0;
    }
};

template <size_t index> struct pack_size_index <index> {
    static const size_t index_v = index;

    static const size_t value(void) { return 0; }
};
```

Usage:

```
//output: 5  (equal to 1 + 4)
std::cout << pack_size_index<2, bool, float, int, double>::value() << std::endl;

//output: 20 (equal to 8 + 8 + 4)
std::cout << pack_size_index<3, double, double, float, int>::value() << std::endl;
```

This gets the job done, but this uses runtime comparison and the resulting executable increases in size rapidly whenever this is used.  What's a less expensive way of doing this?

Comment: It seems like your very close to having a compile time template solution, as for the increase in executable size, variadic templates will do that but it's unavoidable

Comment: Whoever posted the answer and deleted it put it back up because it was right, lol.

Comment: The answer was not running at compile time, isn't that what you want

Comment: Well I just modified it by removing index_v and replacing it with index instead which is a constant expression.  The compile size is still the same though, if that means anything.

Comment: The reason yours and his don't run at compile time is because it calls a function that isn't constexpr, you could easily mark it constexpr if you replaced the if statement with a ternary operator

Comment: He did have a ternary operator.

Comment: Well in any case it looked wrong , I didn't downvote or anything and he didn't argue, I can't remeber what he wrote but it certainly wasn't the entire solution. I would post a sol. but I don't have my computer RN and I don't trust myself to write this kinda program without a compiler

Comment: It was basically `static constexpr size_t value = (index > 0)? (sizeof(type_t) + pack_size_index<index - 1, args...>::value):0;`  Judging by the fact that this compiles with the constexpr modifier, it's a constant expression, right?  Or am I mistaken?

Comment: I deleted my answer, this whole thing ended up being a misunderstanding, I'm tired. Hope I gave you some help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved, I think:

```
template <size_t index, typename... args> struct pack_size_index;

template <size_t index, typename type_t, typename... args>
struct pack_size_index <index, type_t, args...> {
    static const size_t value = (index > 0)?
        (sizeof(type_t) + pack_size_index<index - 1, args...>::value):0;
};

template <size_t index> struct pack_size_index <index> {
    static const size_t value = 0;
};
```

Comment: looks right, you can get rid of the size_t index by using the variadic sizeof... operator. Also can get rid of the second specialization by making sure it never gets to it

Comment: Ah, the size_t index is there because it stops counting byte size after that index, but I can get rid of that specialization.

Comment: Actually it's not letting me get rid of it :/

Comment: I'll post something gimme a minute

Comment: You may alternatively stop the recursion with a specialization when `index == 0`. so no condition is required at all.

Comment: @Jarod42 What's the syntax of that?

Comment: that is:`template <typename... args> struct pack_size_index <0, args...> { static const size_t value = 0; };`.